# Apollo Client version 3 cache update delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

The React application that I have is using `location.pathname` to send a request to my graphql endpoint using `useQuery` It means whenever I change the route, it sends a request to server to receive the new data. The issue I have is while it's in loading state I would like to keep current data so it should act kind of like Youtube when you click on a video. There should be a progress bar on top of the page and when the data is received, then I will display the fresh new data.

But after migrating from version 2 to version 3 I lost this feature. Now it redirects to new page without data and after a few sec when the data is received, it displays the new data.

How can I keep current cache state while I'm sending a request to server?

BTW I have also SSR.

Below is my setup:

```
server.ts

const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: true,
  link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  cache,
  typeDefs,
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 100,
});
```

```
client

const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  cache: cache.restore(apolloState || {}),
  typeDefs,
});
```

```
const usePage = <T = Record<'page', Page>>(options?: Options): QueryResult<T> => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return useQuery<T>(getQuery(options?.fragmentName, options?.fragment), {
    variables: {
      pathname: options?.pathname || pathname,
    },
    ...(options?.queryOptions || {}),
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
};
```

```
App

const App = () => {
  const content = usePage();

  if (content.loading) {
      return <ProgressBar />;
  }

  if (!content) {
      return <NoContent action={pageContent.refetch} />;
  }

  return <Page data={content.data} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there's new property called `previousData` so that we can keep track of the last data that is received. So that we will have something like:

```
const {previousData, data = previousData,} = useQuery()
data?.doSthHere
```

You can also check this link:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6603#issuecomment-700282431